# ASP.NET Table without border attribute

Tags: .net, render

I am creating Table dynamically:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.CssClass="tableclass";
...
pnlPanel.Controls.Add(table);
```

As I result I am getting html code:

```
<table border="0" ...>
```

I do not want to have border attribute at all. I do not want to style table in my code, I want to use CssClass instead.
I have tried to use both of these:

```
tblCalendar.GridLines = GridLines.None;

tblCalendar.Attributes.Remove("border");
```

with no success - I am stil getting border attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the HtmlTable class instead. It's less intrusive if you're primarily going to interact with the table on the client side.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.aspx